# Unique ticket numbers for software support system

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm developing a ticketing system for tracking bugs and software changes using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5. I need a way to pick a unique number from a set of possible numbers. My thought is to create a set of possible numbers and mark numbers from this set as they are used and assigned to a support ticket.

I have this code for generating all possible ticket numbers to choose from, but I want to have leading zeroes so that all ticket numbers have the same length:

```
public static class GenerateNumber
{
    private static IEnumerable<int> GenerateNumbers(int count)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, count);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GenerateTicketNumbers(int count)
    {
        return GenerateNumbers(count).Select(n => "TN" + n.ToString());
    }
}
```

I want the output of
`IEnumerable<string> ticketNumbers = GenerateNumber.GenerateTicketNumbers(Int32.MaxValue);`
 to be something like this:
TN0000000001
.
.
.
TN2147483647

Hopefully we won't need anything as large as `Int32.MaxValue` as that would mean we have way too many bugs haha. I just wanted to be safe than sorry on the limits of the available numbers. Perhaps we could use the methodology of reusing ticket numbers after they have been resolved. However, I don't know how I feel about reuse as it could lead to ambiguity for referring to documentation later on.

Considering the size of this set, is this the most efficient method to go about having unique ticket numbers?

Comment: I do not know if this is a possible solution for you, but you can use the same identity number generated when inserting the record on the DB (if you are using IDENTITY for the primary key of the table), then format the identity number generated any way you want (TN0000001, for example). In this way, you do not need to generate manually the ticket numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an identity column in the database - this will autoincrement for you.

If you need a prefix as well, then store this as a separate varchar column and then for display purposes you can concatenate it (with your requisite leading zeros if that is absolutely really necessary).  Trying to store an incrementing number in a varchar field is going to bite you in the ass one day.

---

As a side note, why the leading zeros?  If I am fixing a ticket, I want to annotate my code with the ticket number.  Leading zeros are just a pain - why not just have TN-123 and have the  number get bigger as required?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about using an identity column in the database. Also, the leading zeros are not a direct requirement. We have our existing ticketing system in Lotus Notes and it adds leading zeros to each ticket number. I was just trying to keep a similar format. It doesn't need to be that way with the new system however.

Comment: Lotus Notes - yikes!  Have you looked at the built in ticketing system that comes with Visual Studio/TFS?

Comment: Yes, we've looked into the ticketing system within Visual Studio/TFS, but our ticketing system also involves non-software related issues. I will select your answer and look at doing a `Int32.ToString()` formatted to add the leading zeros. If it doesn't make sense to have the leading zeros, I'll leave them off.